# Is this the right Stack Exchange site to ask about explaining "undeliverable email notification"?

Tags: support, scope

A friend has given me an email "undeliverable" notification to try to figure out. May I redact the IP addresses and the email address and post it here for assistance in understanding the anatomy of the notification?

Comment: No. Perhaps you could ask this on the [Super User stack exchange site](https://superuser.com/) (though check there [help site](https://superuser.com/help) first), but not on Stack Overflow. Where is there any code of yours involved in this question? How does it involve fixing one of your own programs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that question would not be appropriate for Stack Overflow. It is not about programming, so it is off-topic here.

It *might* be on-topic for another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps a site like [Super User](https://superuser.com/) that deals with the general usage of computers, including hardware and software, like email. It is recommended that you check the site's [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help) first, specifically the page describing [what is on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), before asking on any site.

A master list of Stack Exchange sites is maintained [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites); each has their own Help Center that you can read.